# Nested PHP while loop returns previous results before showing requested results

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I'm working on a double while loop in PHP to show results from a MySQL database in a grouped manner. This is an example of my database structure:

> **id   name   team    country**
>   1    Hamilton    mercedes    uk
>   2    Button    mclaren    uk
>   3    Alonso    mclaren    es
>   4    Perez    mclaren    mx

I want it displayed grouped like this:

```
ES  
Alonso  

MX  
Perez  

UK  
Button  
Hamilton
```

However my nested loop doesn't get any better than this:

```
ES  
Alonso

MX  
Alonso  
Perez  

UK  
Alonso  
Perez  
Button  
Hamilton
```

My loop is failing somewhere or I'm just taking the wrong approach. I tried increments, unnested loops, resetting vars, continue/break, but I can't figure it out. The first loop is to print a table structure per grouping. This is an example of my code:

```
<?php 

// count unique country entries 
$categories = $db->query("  
SELECT DISTINCT country
FROM cms_drivers
WHERE team = '$team'
ORDER BY country
");

while ($cat = $db->fetch_array($categories)) { // loops 3 times  
$custom = $db->query("
    SELECT id, name, team, country
    FROM cms_drivers
    WHERE team = '$team' AND country = '$cat[country]'
    ORDER BY name
");

while ($content = $db->fetch_array($custom)) {
    process('$drivers_bits .= "' . fetch_template('cms_drivers_bits') . '";');
}

process('$drivers .= "' . fetch_template('cms_drivers') . '";');

}
```

Am I overlooking something really simple or is this just the wrong approach?

cms_drivers_bits template:

```
<tr><td>$content[name]</td></tr>
```

cms_drivers template:

```
<table cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0" width="100%">  
<thead>  
<tr>  
<td class="header">  
<span><strong>$cat[country]</strong></span></td>  
</tr>  
</thead>  
<tbody>  
$drivers_bits  
</tbody>  
</table>
```

Comment: It's kind of hard to tell with what you have here. It looks like you're not doing anything with `$content`, unless it's used in `fetch_template()` with `global`. Does `process()` use eval inside?

Comment: Yes, process() uses eval inside and $content is used in the associated template.
  
    <tr>  
    <td>$content[name]</td>
    </tr>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you're getting it looks like you just need to initialize `$drivers_bits` to an empty string before the inner loop.

```
$drivers_bits = '';
while ($content = $db->fetch_array($custom)) { ...
```

`$drivers_bits` is probably used in `fetch_template('cms_drivers')`, and you're appending values to it each time rather than resetting it to the new values for that loop iteration.

Comment: That does remove the duplicates, but it now only shows one result per group. The number of results for ES (one result) also limits the number of results displayed for MX and UK

Comment: That works perfectly! I tried re-initializing $content and $custom to no avail and it never crossed my mind to try it with $drivers_bits.

Comment: Great! glad to hear it.